# SXA Toolbar missing on Customized version of Bootstrap Layout

Tags: sxa

[image]Due to project base markup particularities, such as a different wrapper ID, different disposition of header, footer , we need to create a customized version of SXA's Bootstrap Layout and implement our changes to a separated file.

1) We created a OurProjectGridBody.cshtml with our content

```
@using Sitecore.Mvc

<div id="OurProjectWrapper">
<div id="OurProjectpage">
        @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("header")
        @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("main")
        @Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("footer")
</div>
</div>
```

2) Next created a new definition folder at the path /sitecore/system/Settings/Feature/OurProject

3) At OurProject Grid Definition item (/sitecore/system/Settings/Feature/OurProject/OurProject) we point to our new layout file OurProjectGridBody.cshtml

4) At the Grid Setup item (/sitecore/system/Settings/Feature/OurProject/OurProjectGrid Setup) we selected the new Grid Definition item from step 3

5) Set the Grid for the Site to OurProjectGrid

Now when we open Home (SXA template) in experience editor then it does picks up our newly created OurProjectGrid but I do not see the SXA toolbar.
I do see the different place holders and I can see the option to insert the available renderings but I do not see the SXA tool bar

How do I make the SXA tool bar appear in new custom Grid.

Comment: How will this impact other websites? What about upgrades for the client?

Comment: @MichaelWest this grid is specific to this particular site. Other sites can have their own Grid system. It seems like the div should have the Id=wrapper for the SXA toolbar to show up, otherwise it does not work. We are not using Bootstrap for this site designs.

Comment: Do you use also custom Theme? If you switch to Wireframe, do you see Toolbox?

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: @PeterProcházka I changed the Theme to Wireframe but still the toolbar does not show up. As I mentioned I see the placeholders and also the option to add the SXA components from the available renderings. I just do not see the toolbar.

Comment: @DawidRutkowski I have warnings but no console errors.